# Select SUM using SQL subquery is too slow

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, subquery

I have a "Transaction" table.

A Transaction can have multiple "TransactionProduct".

A Transaction product can have multiple "PriceModifiers".

I have a query that return every transaction products with the total of price modifiers (reduction amount).

The query :

```
SELECT
  TRANSACTION.DESCRIPTION,
  TRANSACTIONPRODUCT.PRODUCTNAME,
  TRANSACTIONPRODUCT.EFFECTIVEPRICE,
    (
        SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
        FROM PRICEMODIFIER 
        WHERE TRANSACTIONPRODUCTID = TRANSACTIONPRODUCT.TRANSACTIONPRODUCTID
    )
    AS REDUCTIONAMOUNT
FROM 
    TRANSACTION,
    TRANSACTIONPRODUCT
WHERE 
   TRANSACTION.TRANSACTIONID = TRANSACTIONPRODUCT.TRANSACTIONID
```

If I remove the subquery with the Sum, the query is very fast to execute.

With the subquery, it takes several seconds...

Any idea how I can improve the query ?

Comment: You could add indexes. Are there any indexes?

Comment: Revenge of the horror-query from the eighties? 1) JOIN syntax 2) table aliases 3) FULLCAPS 4) scalar subqueries 5) "transaction" is a reserved word/keyword; try to avoid is as table/column name

Comment: include the sum subselect as a with clause, include the id aswell and join by id, instead of making a subquery for each row.

Comment: *several seconds* is too slow now?

Comment: No, I don't have indexes. On what should I put them ? Thanks for the advice on the query... I usually don't write SQL queries. (I use an ORM )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  T.DESCRIPTION,
  TP.PRODUCTNAME,
  TP.EFFECTIVEPRICE,
  SUM(PM.AMOUNT)
FROM 
    TRANSACTION T
JOIN TRANSACTIONPRODUCT TP 
    ON T.TRANSACTIONID = TP.TRANSACTIONID
JOIN PRICEMODIFIER PM
    ON PM.TRANSACTIONPRODUCTID = TP.TRANSACTIONPRODUCTID
GROUP BY T.DESCRIPTION, TP.PRODUCTNAME, TP.EFFECTIVEPRICE
```

Answer (score 3):

You should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper `JOIN` syntax.

But that has nothing to do with your performance problem.  For that, you want an index on `PRICEMODIER(TRANSACTIONPRODUCTID, AMOUNT)`.